# Can an mbed device be damaged by something drawing too much current?

Tags: current, mbed

The mbed has a pin which supplies 3.3V regulated current. I think it can supply up to 100mA. If this pin is used to power a device, and the device tries to draw 150mA, then what can happen? Is the mbed in danger of being damaged?

Answer (score 4):

The mbed wiki shows has a [(partial) schematic](http://mbed.org/cookbook/Reference-Design) of the mbed module. It is using a [LD1117S33](http://www.st.com/internet/analog/product/63477.jsp) 3.3v regulator.

This is a 800mA regulator, but it is likely that the mbed's implementation is good for significantly less than that, given the apparent lack of any heatsinking on the voltage regulator.

However, the LD1117 does have internal thermal and current limiting, so it should be pretty bulletproof with regard to damaging it.

Basically, if you draw too much current, the regulator will get hot, the thermal limiting will kick in, and it will reduce the output voltage until it no longer overheats. This *could* cause unexpected/strange behavior in the LPC MCU (unless it has brownout detection), but it shouldn't damage anything.

Basically, you don't need to worry about drawing too much current.

Comment: I think the question is not about damaging the LD1117, but damaging the controller.

Comment: The LD1117 is the only thing involved when too much current is drawn. The MCU may act strangely, but it shouldn't be affected much.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread the question.